# jQuery live update

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the following code in order to update a number in a `<div>`. The code is making my website running slow. I need to update the number every 1 or 2 seconds. How can I make this code work better and never cause the website to slow down?

```
function update_visitors_count(){
   $.post("scripts/dashboard/core.php", {x: x, visits_count: true}, function(data){
            $(".active-users").html(data);
   });
}
setInterval(update_visitors_count, 1000);
```

Comment: some  more info? eg: the post count is related to a user? Is it session related?

Comment: The performance will vary largely, depending on what the server has to do to fulfill the ajax request, as well as the amount of data returned. Please give us more information!

Comment: If you are using ajax post for every second, anyhow the performance will go down. If you really need a real time update to your website use Web Sockets. If web socket is not possible, then for ajax post do not make a new call on every seconds, try to stay on server and hold on untill you get an update and come back when you find an update.

Comment: Yes, it is related to a user and a session.

Comment: I guess you need web sockets...

Comment: @ManishKumar that actually really depends on the scale of website. If it gets a lot of visits, longpolling won't help much. Max Pain, did you measure what - the script itself, the sql query, etc. - are taking the most of the time? Maybe there are some inefficiencies which would lead to slowing the website down? Also, can you 100% confirm that removing the last line in your code makes your website run smooth?

Comment: Yes, just by removing this line setInterval(update_visitors_count, 1000); I was able to view pages and stats with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

As already advised by Manish and John u should try to use a WebSocket.
If you still support older browsers maybe also COMET would be a viable solution.

[Look here for an example](http://jsjoy.com/blog/197/simple-php-comet-example)